# pyodbc Operation Error when I try to access my database it consistently saying server is not found or accessible but docker shows it up and running

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc

Using Docker, I'm creating a SQL Server 2019 image & container and I currently cannot execute my Python script which accesses the database and prints out the results within specific table. the SQL Server is running in a docker container. I'm accessing the script within the terminal which is just a python file located inside my local directory.

Here's my code:

```
import pyodbc
connector = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};' 'Server=cbbcb967dacb;' 'Database=testdb;' 'UID=sa;' 'PWD=Password' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
connector.execute()

cursor = connector.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM inventory')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

The error I get is

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

I downloaded the ODBC driver 18 prior and when I change driver to 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' the error is:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

and when I use 'SQL Server', the code returns the error above. I got the database name by running `select @@servername` and obviously used the password I initially created for the container.

My queries to the database and table are valid as I see the results in terminal:

[image: terminal showing database]

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72664413/edit) your question with more information. Where is the Python script running? Inside the SQL container? Inside another container inside the _same_ Docker network? On the Docker host? How did you create the SQL container - was it in a Docker composition with the Python container? Was it just a `docker run` command on the command line?

Comment: Aside... the result of `select @@SERVERNAME` has no relevance to accessing the Docker container from the outside - that is just the name the container knows itself as and it comes from the `/etc/hostname` file, which is usually just a randomly generated name inherited from the top-level `Dockerfile` in the image history. Other containers needing to access it should use the container's name as was supplied in the `docker-compose.yml` file by the `service`, `container_name`, `domainname`, `hostname` or `aliases` properties, or from the switch equivalents on a `docker run` command line.

Comment: solely just ```docker run``` on the command line and the SQL container is alone with the python script being a local file on my computer @AlwaysLearning

Comment: How you access it from the Docker host depends on how you published it. e.g.: if you used `-p 127.0.0.1:1234:1433` then you'd use `Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1234` from Python because it needs to connect to the IPv4 localhost. Also you supplied both UID+PWD parameters along with `Trusted_Connection=yes;` - don't do that. Trusted_Connection is used to enable Windows Authentication, which won't work with Docker containers unless you've gone through the pain of installing Kerberos 5 client services and joining the container to the Windows/Active Directory domain. So just use UID+PWD without it.